# My print functions asking for input display after the input

Tags: java

[Screenshot of the code running in Netbeans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EInJ.png)
When writing simple programs that receive input from the user, the prompt only displays after the input.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        int number = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

When I run it, Netbeans waits for an input before displaying any kind of text. The above code looks like this in the console:

```
5  
Enter a number:  
5
```

Comment: What happens if you run it off the command line?  If I run your code in IntelliJ, it behaves as expected - it prints first before waiting for input.

Comment: I'm not at all experienced with running from the command line, but everything I've wrote in the IDE that receives an input behaves like this.

Comment: I ran the code on both eclipse and using a normal linux terminal. 
I get the below output on terminal
> java sample.Example
Enter a number: 5

5

I don't see anything wrong with the code the way you are suggesting

Comment: Yeah, it just doesn't make any sense. My professor didn't understand the issue either.

Comment: Try flushing. Integrated consoles do not always behave like normal terminals for a variety of reasons and can lead to unexpected out ordering (e.g., if you switched `System.out` to `System.err`, which is generally flushed earlier, it might "work").

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue as you using Netbeans. I tried running the code in another IDE and it works as it should. My take is that it's an issue with Netbeans, at the moment the only work around I found is using println.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

use println instead of print, you will be happy.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29779698)